# Python Image Scaling

Tags: python, image, resize, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to scale a screenshot using this code :

```
im = Image.open(img_path)
im = im.resize((newWidth,newHeight),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

but this results in a very low quality image especially texts are impossible to read

**Original**

[**Click for original Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKx2n.png)

**Scaled**

[**Click for scaled Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3bHg.png)

I have tried other algorithms in PIL but none of them gives the result I wanted.

I actually tried to resize my images inside Office PowerPoint and texts are clear and readable.

**PowerPoint scaled**

[**Click for Office scaled Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSPuD.png)

Are there any other ways which I can scale the Images ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

it had worked for me.

```
import imutils 
im = imutils.resize(im, width=Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

if you want for details, you can examine https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/93640/imutils.resize